# Scrolling element contents without javascript

Tags: css, xhtml

Dear all, is there a way to scroll, as in relatively shift the contents of, an element *without* using javascript, and only using CSS?

If that matters, the element in question has overflow:hidden and white-space: nowrap to make it 'hide' some parts of its content. The element is normally scrollable with javascript, but needs to be properly shifted upon initial rendering (and without further interactive scrolling, of course) in case javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not with CSS directly.

You could simulate it, by wrapping the contents with a div and giving it a `margin-top` value for the amount of scrolling you want.

(*remember to remove it/set it to 0 with javascript when it is enabled*)

**update**
A cool idea is what Jamie, mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707241/scrolling-element-contents-without-javascript/4707266#4707266), if it fits your requirements.

---

**update 2**

Here is another solution i created out of Jamie's idea, that needs no frames.

Put an anchor `<a name="anchor_name">..</a>` at the place you want the scrolling to be and use a

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=#anchor_name_here">
```

to auto-scroll there. (*the meta element should go in the head though for (x)html conformance*)

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/f3CVY/5/

works great in all browsers i tested it (*IE, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari*)

Comment: looks even cooler! it wouldn't work for horizontal scrolling, would it?

Comment: Nice lateral thinking there Gaby. I'd never seriously recomend anyone use the meta refresh, or even the iframes option is described above, but as an excersise in thinking out of the box, this is pretty ace :)

Comment: @etranger, it should work if you have set your contents in a way to be able to scroll horizontally. (simple example http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/f3CVY/9/)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to scroll items on a page (unless it's an iframe with the hash portion of the url included, in which case the browser will control the initial positioning of the scroll, not css or html) using only CSS and HTML.

Comment: this is a cool idea indeed, but shifting to iframes is an overkill for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another method - which is quite hacky - but it works without a reload.

The solution I've created works in the following browsers:

- Firefox 4+
- Safari 5+
- Chrome 6+
- Opera 11+
- IE 10+
- Android 2.3+

It's really a bit hacky, so see whether you would use it or not. :)

**A little explanation**

I used the HTML5 attribute `autofocs` on an `<input>`-field. As this will focus the input, it has to get it into the viewport. Therefor it will scroll to the given position. To get rid of the highlighted outline and to not see the input at all, you have to set some styles. But this still forced Safari to have one blinking pixel, so I did the trick with the span, that acts like an overlay. Note that you can't simply use `display: none` as this won't trigger the autofocus (only tested this in Safari).

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/UDuqe/)

The demo will run in Safari and Chrome only. IE and Firefox seem to not fire autofocus in an `<iframe>`.

**CSS**

```
div.outer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div.inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

div.inner > input {
    width: 1px;
    height:1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
}

div.inner > span {
    width: 1px;
    height:1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    background: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">  
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text" autofocus></input>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```